# Dynamically scrollable textview for a single row

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I want to get multiple textviews or listviews in a single row, which should be scrollable. How can I set an action for that?

Instead of getting a dynamic textview orlist view like

```
helo1

helo2

helo3
.
.
.(scrollable like horizontal)
```

I want them in a single row like this, and it should be scrollable:

```
helo1 helo2 helo3.......
```

New columns should be added dynamically and scrollable (vertically), and actions should be set for them.

Comment: Use recycler view with horizontal orientation.. If thats you want lemme know..

Comment: you want horizontal scroll

Comment: You need to try out https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders

Comment: I have edited your question - if you want to further improve it, you can show what you've tried so far and where specifically you got stuck. It the moment it's just a vague specification for somebody else.